# How to create an iterative structure?

Tags: c, iteration

I have created some code that has multiple functions, and when an X value is entered it outputs a line that has computed the number for the given X value and h value that has been declared. However, in the terminal it only outputs one line of each value, and I need to implement some type of iterative structure that varies h from 10^-1 to 10^-8. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    double u(double x)
    {
        return(pow(x,3.0));
    }

    double dudx(double x)
    {
        return(3.0 * pow(x,2.0));
    }

    double fdiff(double x, double h)
    {
        return((u(x+h) - u(x))/h);
    }

    double bdiff(double x, double h)
    {
        return((u(x) - u(x-h))/h);
    }

    double cdiff(double x, double h)
    {
        return((u(x+h)-u(x-h))/(2*h));
    }

    double fderr(double x, double h)
    {
        return(fabs(fdiff(x,h)-dudx(x)));
    }


    double bderr(double x, double h)
    {
        return(fabs(bdiff(x,h)-dudx(x)));
    }

    double cderr(double x, double h)
    {
        return(fabs(cdiff(x,h)-dudx(x)));
    }


double x;
double h=1.0 * pow(10,-1.0);

    printf("Enter an Integer ");
    scanf("%lf",&x);
    printf("u(x): %lf du/dx: %lf fd: %lf bd: %lf cd: %lf fderr: %lf bderr: %lf cderr: %lf\n", u(x), dudx(x), fdiff(x,h), bdiff(x,h), cdiff(x,h), fderr(x,h), bderr(x,h), cderr(x,h));

}
```

I'm pretty sure I have to use some type of for loop around this area:

```
double h=1.0 * pow(10,-1.0);
```

But, I do not know how to implement it! So to reiterate, how do I create an iterative structure that starts with an h value of 10^-1 and ends with 10^-8?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The code you show isn't standard C. Standard C doesn't have nested functions.

Comment: As for your problem, do you know about loops? Have you tried creating a loop from `-1` to `-8`?

Comment: Oh and you don't need the call to `pow` really. Initialize `h` to `0.1`, then in your loop divide by `10` each iteration.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with loops? Could you give me an example of one I could work off of for this? Thanks! @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: I'm sorry, but you have to get a book about C to learn such basic things! Or pay better attention in class.